# Style switcher, how to define sub folder?

Tags: jquery, stylesheet

I am trying to build a css style switcher. How can I define sub folder for stylesheet files? Currently if stylesheet files are in root folder the script works fine. When I put stylesheet files under `/css` folder then it stops working.

Directory tree:

root
index.html
--css
----blue.css
----green.css
----yellow.css
----grey.css
--js
----core.js
----jquery.js

Any advice how can I fix it? Here is the [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/SuDuh/)

```
(function ($j) {
    switch_style = {
        onReady: function () {      
            this.switch_style_click();
        },

        switch_style_click: function(){
            $(".box").click(function(){
                var id = $(this).attr("id");
                $("#switch_style").attr("href", id + ".css");
            });
        },
    };

    $j().ready(function () {
        switch_style.onReady();
    });
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: not sure what you want, can't you just use `"css/" + id + ".css"` ?

Comment: Simple css/ doesn't work. I just want to change the target path of css files.

Comment: Please show the directory tree.

Comment: root
--css
--js
index.html

Comment: what about `"/css/" + id + ".css"` ? if you open your console you should see some `404 Errors`, look and see how the link is created.

Comment: I've uploaded whole script with directory here: http://mab.to/t3LMTmnOo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like Spokey said, you have to specify the path like this:

```
$(".box").click(function(){
    var id = $(this).attr("id"),
        path = "css/" + id + ".css";
    $("#switch_style").attr("href", path);
});
```

Or, if you have css stylesheets in different folders, you can set a "data" attribute with complete path to the switching divs instead of ids

```
<div class="box" data-href="css/green.css"></div>
<div class="box" data-href="css2/red.css"></div>
<div class="box" data-href="css3/blue.css"></div>
<div class="box" data-href="css4/yellow.css"></div>
```

and then obtain the path like this:

```
$(".box").click(function(){
    var path = $(this).data("href");
    $("#switch_style").attr("href", path);
});
```